# if statement followed by return 0

Tags: c++, control-flow

I have some code like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string question;

    std::getline(std::cin, question);
    
    if (question == "yes") {
        std::cout << "Let's rock and roll!" << std::endl;
        return 0; // This line
    } if (question == "no") {
        std::cout << "Too bad then..." << std::endl;   
    } else {
        std::cout << "What do you mean by that?" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I don't write the commented `return 0` line and input `yes`, the output is `Let's rock and roll!` followed by `What do you mean by that?`. It should only output `Let's rock and roll!`.

But I don't need to put `return 0` in the `if (question=="no"){...}` block. If I input `no`, the output is just `Too bad then...`.

Why do I need the `return 0` in the first case, but not the second?

Comment: You want `} else if (question == "no") {`.

Comment: *"Also, any references for learning c++ would be highly appreciated."* -- please remove this from your question. Asking for recommendations is explicitly off-topic, as is asking more than one question in a single question.

Comment: Example code should be focused on the issue (the "minimal" part of "[mre]"). For this code, you could define `question` then skip to the line `std::cout<<"(yes/no)"<<std::endl;`. Asking for an age and name has no bearing on how you process the response to the "yes/no" prompt. (Yes, I suggest skipping the line that explains what you intend "yes" and "no" to mean.) Even better, you could define `std::string question = "yes"; // Would be obtained from the user` and skip right to the `if` statement you are asking about.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Why?" Well, did you try to think through what will happen? Do you understand what `return` does? What do you think it does?

Comment: "Also, any references for learning c++ would be highly appreciated." Please note that this is **not a discussion forum**. We do not make such recommendations here, we answer one question at a time, and we do not "help people learn"; we **answer questions**. Please read [ask] and follow the [tour].

Comment: Please note the [edit]s I made to the question, to understand how it is done properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Control flow is your issue here:

```
     if(question == "yes"){
        std::cout<<"Lets rock and roll!"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
     }if (question == "no"){
        std::cout<<"Too bad then..."<<std::endl;   
     } else{
        std::cout<<"What do you mean by that?"<<std::endl;
     }
```

Let's format this a bit better by surrounding if/else statements/blocks with newlines and adding some whitespace around operators.

```
     if (question == "yes") {
        std::cout << "Lets rock and roll!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
     }

     if (question == "no") {
        std::cout << "Too bad then..." << std::endl;   
     } 
     else {
        std::cout << "What do you mean by that?" << std::endl;
     }
```

These are two different conditionals. The first one being triggered does not stop the second if/else from being evaluated. In fact, if `question` equals `"yes"` then it *cannot* equal `"no"` so the else clause in the second if/else must be executed.

By including `return 0;`  in the first conditional block, the function exits *immediately*, thus skipping everything after it. The second if/else is not evaluated and `"What do you mean by that?"` is never printed.

You likely wanted this to be a single if/else. Now only one of these blocks will be executed. Because an `else` is included as a catch-all in the event none of the previous conditions were met, it is guaranteed one branch will be executed.

```
     if (question == "yes") {
        std::cout << "Lets rock and roll!" << std::endl;
     }
     else if (question == "no") {
        std::cout << "Too bad then..." << std::endl;   
     } 
     else {
        std::cout << "What do you mean by that?" << std::endl;
     }
```